# E2001 Ordinal type required

Tags: delphi

Here facing some errors on Ordinal type required, please help me to check it out from the following code:

**Extracted from comments:**

```
Program Test;    
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}    
Type
  TResourceSet = set of 0..127;
var
  N : TResourceSet;
  i : Int64;
begin
  i := 127;
  N := N + [i];  // E2001 Ordinal type required
end.
```

Comment: Please show actual code, properly formatter (see the help) and in the format of a [mcve]

Comment: You need to give us the declarations of `TResourceSet`, `i`, `j` and the line that gives the error.

Comment: TResourceSet is a set and both i and j is Int64.  the error is happening bcz of N

Comment: A set of what? The base type of a set [must](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) be an ordinal type of maximum size byte. Hence, 64-bit integers are way too large. A hypothetical variable of type `set of Int64` would require 2 EB (2147483648 GB). You almost certainly don't have enough RAM for that.

Comment: the TResourceSet = set of TResourceSetrange 0........127  """""""    begin

  Skip('=');
  repeat
    ReduceLongintExpression(i, Low(TResourceRange), High(TResourceRange));
    if TestAndSkip('..') then begin
      ReduceLongintExpression(j, Low(TResourceRange), High(TResourceRange));
     if j < i then
        RaiseParserError('End of range is below start');
       N := N + [i..j]
    end
    else
      N := N + [i];
  until not TestAndSkip(',');
  Skip(';')
end;

Comment: @LobsangTashi: Now you didn't follow David's correct advice. Not only isn't it properly formatted, it also isn't a minimal reproducible example, partly because you forgot to tell us the definition of `Skip`, `ReduceLongintExpression`, `TResourceRange`, `TestAndSkip`, and `RaiseParserError`. The definition of `TResourceSet` is the most important one. Surely you did click on the link David gave you, and surely you took the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) when you registered your account?

Comment: If you had completed the [tour], you would have the *Informed* badge. These things are important. Don't post the question in comments. In the [tour] it will explain that topics here are wikis, you can and should edit the question to improve it when this is necessary.

Comment: `Int64` is not an allowed ordinal type. At least for use with a set operation. Use `Integer` instead.

Comment: @LURD: No, as I wrote in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716818/e2001-ordinal-type-required#comment116191677_65716818), the maximum size is 8 bits for the base type. (A 32-bit base type would make a set type of size 512 MB.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, I don't know what you mean. Integer is a perfectly valid ordinal type for working with a set. Of course the value must be restricted to `0..255`, but that is irrelevant in this questions, since the compiler disallows the use of 64 bit integers. Hence the message `Ordinal type required`.

Comment: @LURD: It seems like we are talking about different things. I was talking about about base types of sets, and then indeed the limit is a byte (8 bits). `type TTest = set of Integer` will not compile. I tried to make this explicit by explicitly using the word "base type". It seems like you are talking about the situation `type TTest = set of Byte; var t: TTest; t := [i]` where `var i: Integer` which is indeed allowed (but not `var i: Int64`). It wasn't immediately clear to me that your cmt "Int64 is not an allowed ordinal type. At least for use with a set operation." was about this situation.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, can we have this question reopened, please. I think closing this question was a bit harsh since it has a simple answer.

Comment: @LURD: Sure, with your edit it does become an answerable Q. But the original version very much wasn't. It didn't even mention Int64!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

64 bit types cannot be used in set operations. Hence the compiler error `E2001 Ordinal type required`.

I cannot find any documentation as to why the compiler disallows that. Some details in [Ordinal Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Ordinal_Types) states that `Int64` does not qualify for use with certain ordinal functions.

Anyway in order to make it work you can declare the type as `Integer` or copy your 64 bit integer to a byte.

```
Program Test;    
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}    
Type
  TResourceSet = set of 0..127;
var
  N : TResourceSet;
  i : Int64;
  j : Byte;
  k := Integer;
begin
  i := 127;
  j := i;
  k := i;
  N := N + [j];  // Ok
  N := N + [k];  // ok
end.
```

Or, as suggested by @Andreas, use a type cast:

```
N := N + [Byte(i)];
```

Comment: Another option: `N := N + [Byte(i)]`.